# Como fazer duas clausulas WHERE dentro de um WITH aninhado

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código

```
$sectors = Sector::where('company_id', $id)
                 ->where('status', '0')
                 ->with('charges.levels')
                 ->get();
```

e preciso de 3 condições

- Status do **sector** seja **0**
- Status do **charges** seja **0**
- Status do **levels** seja **0**

Sendo assim eu gostaria de saber:

- Como faço para usar um WHERE que busque o status do charge 0 e o status dos levels 0 sendo que eles estão em um nested `with`: `->with('charges.levels')`

O código segue a hierarquia de que:

- Um setor possui um ou mais cargos e um cargo pertence a um setor somente.
- Um cargo possui um ou mais níveis e um nível pertence a um cargo somente.

Levando em conta que quero trazer todos os levels onde o level seja status 0, o cargo status 0 e o setor status 0

Comment: Acho que é isto que queres: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Não posso comentar ainda então irei comentar aqui, poderia postar seus models, migrations se utilizar e os devidos relacionamentos para análise?

Comment: Qual a versão do laravel você está usando?

Answer (score 1):

[Um exemplo bem claro no site é que você pode utilizar na carga adiantada condições](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads), exemplo:

```
$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}])->get();
```

no seu código seria assim:

```
$sectors = Sector::where('company_id', $id)
             ->with(['charges' => function ($query) {
                   $query->where('status', 0);
                  },'charges.levels' => function($query) {
                    $query->where('status', 0);
                  }])
             ->get();
```

**Ref.** [Eloquent: Relationships - Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar passados ​​como array:

```
$query->where([
    ['column_1', '=', 'value_1'],
    ['column_2', '<>', 'value_2'],
    [COLUMN, OPERATOR, VALUE],
    ...
])
```

**Condições usando Array:**

```
$users = User::where([
       'column1' => value1,
       'column2' => value2,
       'column3' => value3
])->get();
```

Irá produzir consulta como abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column1=value1 and column2=value2 and column3=value3
```

Comment: Mas o problema é que status do charges fica na tabela charges, e status dos levels fica na tabelas levels, eu tinha feito dessa maneira, porém quando coloquei where('charges.status', '0'), resultou em que charges.status não era uma coluna

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você procura é algo semelhante à isso, tente o seguinte:

```
$sector = Sector::whereHas('charges', function ($query) use ($search) {
         $query->where('levels', $search);
    })->with('charges.levels')->where('company_id', $id)->get();
```

Espero ter ajudado.